# Plugin to run js timeout

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap

I need a plugin for a cordova application that executes an application-independent javascript block, and even if the application is in the background or even terminated that block will continue to execute. I researched and found this one here https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-js-service that apparently would suit my need, I set up correctly in my project, but for some reason it didn't work because it gave error in time to compile, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please share the error details you are getting, @LucasSouza?

Comment: phonegap run android --info
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run android --info' ...
Android Studio project detected


ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Principal\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151

studio

Subproject Path: CordovaLib


Subproject Path: app


publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now
published.

The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be re
moved in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_dj4sxhs0taycsl9sx9uqrv681.run(C:\Users\Principal\background\pla
tfo